# Can you make some code not run when you deploy the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, morgan

beforehand i apologies for my bad english

Morgan is awesome to develop, and see what happens. But what do i do when i want to deploy my server and dont what to see everybody who is on. 
How do you make it so somethings don't execute when it is deployed?
and should morgan be an external script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably want to use an environment variable, notably `NODE_ENV`, to tell your server which setting it's in. Set it to 'development' when you're running locally, and 'production' on your server. You can access it in your Node application as `process.env.NODE_ENV`. If you don't want morgan to run in production do something like this:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  app.use(morgan());
}
```

To manually set an env var when you run your server, run like `NODE_ENV=development node app.js`.

You should make sure that the variable is set to something. You can default it to 'development' like this:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an environment variable called NODE_ENV. If you google it, you can find extensive information on it.

For instance:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = "production";

if(process.env.NODE_ENV == "development") {
  console.log("This log will only be visible in development environment");
}
```